# How to show limited number of items in different categories using drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have a different categories like category1,category2,category3 and so on. Also, items exists in each category like item1,item2,item3,item4  and so on.

I want to show only 3 items for each category and add `show more` button below each category to show all items in each category.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using taxonomy for category1, category2 and category3.

Easiest way I believe is setup views block for each category. embed the views block into the page.

Or you can create just one view block with the category term as contextual filter. Then you need embed the view with code in the page template for node template wherever it is needed.